# Move bootbox modal across page while dragging

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, drag-and-drop, bootbox, html5-draggable

I am building an electron app in which I show a bootbox alert with a className of `settingsModal`.Now I was wondering.Is there any way to move this alert across the page by using native drag and drop api?(Don't want to use jQuery UI).
Here is the code for my bootbox alert:

```
 $("#settings").on("click", function() {
        alert({
            title: "Select settings",
            message: `
            <form>
                <label for='category1'>1st category title</label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control' name='category1'/>
                <label for='category2'>2nd category title</label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control' name='category2'/>
                <label for='category3'>3rd category title</label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control' name='category3'/>
                <label for='category4'>4th category title</label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control' name='category4'/>
            </form>
            `,
            buttons: {
                ok: {
                    label: "Save settings",
                    className: "btn-success"
                }
            },
            className: "settingsModal",
            callback: function() {
                var title1 = $("[name='category1']").val();
                var title2 = $("[name='category2']").val();
                var title3 = $("[name='category3']").val();
                var title4 = $("[name='category4']").val();
                if (isEmpty(title1, title2, title3, title4)) {
                    alert("Please fill in all inputs");
                } else {
                    var titleElements = $(".categoryTitle");
                    var titles = [title1, title2, title3, title4];
                    for (var i = 0; i < titleElements.length; i++) {
                        $(titleElements[i]).text(titles[i])
                    }
                }
            }
        });
         //When settings modal appears make it draggable
        $(".settingsModal").attr("draggable",true);
    });
```

Comment: Bootbox doesn't support dragging. There was a [pull-request](https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/pull/382) for adding that functionality, but it wasn't added. You can fork the repo and pull in that request if you want draggable modals.